# Generate wheel - canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

So ok - I would like to generate a kind of a **spinning wheel** with a canvas and JS. My wheel should have 10 segments, which I saved as a .png file.

[image: img]

I want to draw 10 segments in a for loop to get a "full circle".

[image: img]

This is the code I have so far. Unfortunately the "wheel" looks pretty destroyed - I can't find my mistake.

```js
const segmentCount = 10;

let initializeWheel = function() {
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let size = $(window).width() * 0.9;
  canvas.width = canvas.height = size;
  ctx.fillStyle = "red"
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size)
  for (let segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < segmentCount; segmentIndex++) {
    let image = new Image()
    image.onload = function() {
      let h = ((size / 2) / image.width) * image.height,
        w = size / 2;
      let x = size / 4,
        y = h;
      let degrees = segmentIndex * (360 / segmentCount)
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(x + w / 2, y + h / 2);
      ctx.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180.0);
      ctx.translate(-x - w / 2, -y - h / 2);
      ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, w, h);
      ctx.restore();
    };
    image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PqtU.png"
  }
  $(canvas).appendTo(document.body)
}

initializeWheel()
```

```css
canvas {
  position: "absolute";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: "auto";
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is part of the issue, but Canvas uses radians, not degrees for circle/arc geometry. `2 * Math.PI` gets you 360 degrees IIRC.

Comment: Please have another look at my code Scott :)

Comment: That's why I said "not sure if this is part of the issue". I'm not a geometry/Math guy and wasn't sure what your code was doing. Just wanted to make sure you knew. I saw a reference to 360 degrees and wondered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. No need of images but if you want you can.

I'm drawing the first segment starting in the origin. Next I'm rotating the segment. Also I'm moving the context in the center of the canvas. I hope it helps.

```js
const segmentCount = 10;

let initializeWheel = function() {
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let size = $(window).width() * 0.9;
  canvas.width = canvas.height = size;
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
  let r = 200;// the radius of the wheel
  let degrees = 2*Math.PI / segmentCount;
  function drawSegment(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(r,0);
    ctx.arc(0,0,r,0,degrees);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  ctx.translate(size/2,size/2); // translate the context in the center.
  for (let segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < segmentCount; segmentIndex++) {
  drawSegment()
  ctx.rotate(degrees);
  }
  $(canvas).appendTo(document.body)
}

initializeWheel()
```

```css
canvas {
  position: "absolute";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: "auto";
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP comments that they need to use the image. Next I'm using the same logic as above, but this time I'm using the image. I had to scale down the context since the image was too big.

```js
const segmentCount = 10;

let initializeWheel = function() {
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let size = $(window).width() * 0.9;
  canvas.width = canvas.height = size;
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
  //let r = 200;
  let degrees = 2*Math.PI / segmentCount;
  function drawSegment(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(r,0);
    ctx.arc(0,0,r,0,degrees);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  ctx.translate(size/2,size/2);
  ctx.scale(.7,.7);// the image is too big. I have to scale down the image.
  let image = new Image();
  image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PqtU.png"
  image.onload = function() {
  for (let segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < segmentCount; segmentIndex++) {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, -image.height, image.width, image.height);
  //drawSegment()
  ctx.rotate(degrees);
  }
  }
  $(canvas).appendTo(document.body)
}

initializeWheel()
```

```css
canvas {
  position: "absolute";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: "auto";
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But I want to make use of images as I mentioned. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. This time I'm using your image. Please take a look.

Comment: I don't see an image. Just a big black circle.

Comment: Of coarse, since your image is a black sector of circle. To see the image try `for (let segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < segmentCount; segmentIndex+=2) {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, -image.height, image.width, image.height);
  ctx.rotate(degrees*2);
  }`

Comment: It's not my image - I didn't post the question. You're not using the image the OP was referring to.